# How is greensock's TweenMax able to change multiple css properties at the same time

Tags: javascript

I'm just curious about the inner-workings of GS's TweenMax. Also, if you do not mind answering this as well, does TweenMax run separate animation calls on the same object at the same, or are the animations initiated as they are executed by the javascript engine?

Comment: How about studying the [code](https://github.com/greensock/GreenSock-JS/tree/master/src/uncompressed) ;)

Comment: How about I ask here first before I go about studying hundred lines of code